# Front Top Strut Assembly Bearing Mix Match

Tags: bearing, struts

I have a previous post in regards to a top strut mount bearing issue with my struts. I understand OEM part replacement may do the job, although for how long if at all. Due to the material/construction of the bearing I don't have much faith in its purpose based on my research and advice from others.

I have been looking at several different cars and their bearings types/strut part configurations, in order to try and find one that could be compatible with mine of far greater quality/sturdiness. I understand I would have to measure exact sizes and dimensions to ensure they are a perfect or near perfect fitment.

[image]

**Please note some of the pictures have been resized so are not a clear representation of the items actual size.**

I would omit my Nissan Almera thrust bearing and upper seat mount as that is already incorporated in the Ford Mondeo one. I'd need to measure that the outer lip on my strut mount insulator is identical to the lip on the Ford Mondeo one and there is enough clearance. There would be a vertical difference vertically once assembled which could mean more tension on the coil spring.

- Has anyone ever tried anything similar?
- Any advise for any other makes/model parts to look at that could have a similar setup/fixture?
- Any advice/why this might not be such a good idea?

Comment: Sorry, no experience. Just a tought: There often exist "upgraded modells" of certain components, suited for heavy duty. For example strut springs, bushings etc.. suited and approved for the car, without any different handling or legal issues. Perhaps something like that exists for your car?

On another note: I don't know about your jurisdiction, but I'd rather replace my struts every two years than facing the risks (in case of an accident and discovery of an non-matching part my insurance coverage would be void)

Comment: If you were to investigate doing this, wouldn’t you be better just looking for a generic thrust bearing of silimalar size to your original, for example just search for “sealed thrust bearing” on eBay.

Comment: @Martin I have already searched the specific OEM part number for whatever different variation may exist with no luck. It's a generic 2006 (Nissan Almera N16) car, probably not that popular either. Don't think an upgraded version would exist without burning a hole in my pocket for some expensive aftermarket suspension set. Good point with the safety aspect, hence asking for advice, as to me (I know no better) doesn't seem to be such a huge variation parts wise also considering the components use. To just enable the turning? With mine currently binding, could also be considered unsafe?

Comment: @HandyHowie Will have a look now, not sure why I didn't investigate this further before. I think the issue of a generic one not having a top lip of the thurst bearing pictured which sort of slots into the strut mount insulator put me off. Does seem like a better/more viable alternative.

Comment: @Dave1UK One thing is that your current bearing is binding. While not good, it is something that happens by wear&tear, without you causing this actively. As long as the MOT check won't complain, you should be covered by your insurance (IANAL). Installling a totally different part is different. The design of the car got approved for motorized traffic. Replacing parts with using spares of the same approval number won't change the approval of your car. Installing a totally different part from an another vehicle model should void that approval.

Comment: Should the worst case happen and you are involved in an accident, and somebody found that part that doesn't belong there then it is upon to you to explain that that part didn't contributed to the accident. This is difficult, expensive, if not possible for suspension parts

Comment: Please note: That is my understanding (IANAL) of the situation in my jurisdiction. It may be totally different for yours. I just want to point out that there could be other, legal problems lingering when using parts from another vehicle models..